# source and header files

Tags: c++, c

I'm facing difficulty in understanding source and header files stuff.
Suppose

1)I have a source file(`functions.cpp`) which contains function named 'int add(int x,int y)' in the location `/Users/xyz/Desktop/functions.cpp`.

2)The header file(`functions.h`) which contain the **declaration** of the functions in source file(functions.cpp) is placed in `/Users/xyz/Documents/function.h`

3)Other source file(`main.cpp`) which contain 'main()' function need to call the 'add()' function defined in 'functions.cpp'.The source file 'main.cpp' is located in `/Users/xyz/Downloads/main.cpp`

I'm placing these files in different locations so that i can understand these concepts better.

So,how do i link `function.cpp` to `main.cpp` using `functions.h`.

```
   #include "   "
```

What is the path that i should use in the above `include`?

Also,it is my understanding that .h files provides the **declaration** of functions which are **defined** some where else and  having a declaration is necessary for the compiler to call the functions which are **defined** in some other files or functions which are not **defined** yet. Is that right? Please correct me in case I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first question has no answer. C++ does not define how header files are found, it's up to the compiler and they all do it a bit differently. If you want an answer you'll have to look up the details in the documentation of your compiler. I would recommend you put everything the same directory and stop worrying about it.

In the second part of your question, your understanding seems pretty good to me.

Answer (score 5):

```
#include "functions.h"
```

Your code should **not** know about how you choose to arrange your source tree. To hard-code paths is to earn the hatred of whoever has to maintain this code (and that includes you six months from now).

Your build system -- whatever it is -- can deal with the paths. That could be as simple as:

```
g++ -I/Users/xyz/Documents -c functions.cpp
```

Your statement of how declarations/definitions work is basically correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should include in your main the exact path to your header file:

```
#include "/Users/xyz/Documents/function.h"
```

Hope this help.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You include `functions.h` in `functions.cpp` and `main.cpp` using `#include` then you compile both `main.cpp` and `functions.cpp`. The linker then links the two resulting object files. Your inclusion of functions.h in main.cpp will allow you to call the functions from functions.h within your main.cpp file

As for paths of files, provided that you specify to your compiler the required paths in which to find your code you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a full path

```
#include "/Users/xyz/Documents/function.h"
```

or a relative path (which is usually more preferable)

```
#include "../Documents/function.h"
```

Don't forget to specify full or relative paths to your `.obj` files when you are linking the final executable as well ;)